# How do I use css to style an element which has a JS-generated classname?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to port a long-running pet project of mine (A Java chess application) to the web using HTML/CSS/JS, but am not very experienced in web development.
What I want to do is use the classname of my board squares ( elements) to denote what color they should be set to by the css. 
The  elements are all JS-generated as shown in my code snippet, and I have verified that each square's classname is being correctly set. The CSS doesn't seem to be changing the background color properly however.

Any tips/pointers appreciated :)

```js
function generateBoardHTML() {
    var chessBoard = document.getElementById('chessBoard');

    for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
        var boardRow = chessBoard.insertRow(row);

        for (var col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            var boardSquare = boardRow.insertCell(col);

            boardSquare.id = '(' + row + ',' + col + ')';
            boardSquare.class = (row + col) % 2 == 0 ? 'whiteSquare' : 'blackSquare';
            //boardSquare.innerHTML = boardSquare.class;
        }
    }
}

generateBoardHTML();
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}

.whiteSquare {
    background-color: white;
}

.blackSquare {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<table id='chessBoard'>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several CSS properties that have weird names when you reference then in JavaScript.  `class` is one of them. *(`for` is the other, which becomes `labelFor`.)*

```
boardSquare.className = (row + col) % 2 == 0 ? 'whiteSquare' : 'blackSquare';
```

*Historical note:  Under ES3 you cannot use reserved words as property names and `class` is a reserved word.  While this doesn't matter in ES5, this convention is already pretty much set in stone.*

Reference:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

Comment: @Rayon Never said it was.  However, `class` cannot be used as a property name under ES3, so `class` was mapped to `className` when accessing the property via JavaScript, as the link I provided explains.

Comment: That's odd. Thank you :)

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, I know you what you mean.. Just a choice of words is what creates confusion.. _"There are several properties that have.."_ would go well :)

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Jeremy J Starcher you can use `className` to add a class to an element generated using javascript.

But you can also you `classList` property, which return a list of class attached to the element.

It has two useful method `add` & `remove`a class from the element.

```
function generateBoardHTML() {
    var chessBoard = document.getElementById('chessBoard');

    for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
        var boardRow = chessBoard.insertRow(row);

        for (var col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            var boardSquare = boardRow.insertCell(col);

            boardSquare.id = '(' + row + ',' + col + ')';
            //Changed here
            boardSquare.classList.add((row + col) % 2 == 0 ? 'whiteSquare' : 'blackSquare');
            //boardSquare.innerHTML = boardSquare.class;
        }
    }
}

generateBoardHTML();
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/dd3ur8ww/)

Comment: I didnt' know about classList. Thanks :)